# What are the hidden assumptions for surface of cylinder equaling area of a rectangle?

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

Are there cases were unrolling/flattening a surface ( not sure what the name of the process is, maybe area preserving?) does not equal the unflattened/unrolled form? The motivation for asking this question is as follows :

When trying to calculate length of a helix, the following two methods give the same answer

1. using an arc length integral or
2. unrolling the cylinder ( e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ce64D_yGDvY )

the problem with 2 is that the process is not mathematically justified to be area preserving, although intuitively it does make sense and happens to also match he correct answer by 1.

my question is under what conditions process 2 is justified, or an example of when no amount of flattening/unrolling will not work/correct? (I am looking for something similar to examples for every where continuous function being no where differentiable for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function)

Comment: What do you mean by "flattening"/"unrolling"? If you mean an isometry with a region on a plane that preserves lengthes, then, by definition, it preserves lengthes.

Comment: By the way, what definitions of *length* and *area* do you use?

Comment: @Alexey : I am happy with any defintions, I think one of the hidden conditions that makes process 2 area preserving is that it is happening in Euclidean space/geometry, I am not sure under hyperbolic or spehrical geometry the process 2 would still be area preserving.

Comment: @Alexey : regarding definition of area, imagin a circle drawn on surface of a sphere,   the area of circle on surface of sphere is not unique. If a sphere can caue area to have 2 values, how we could continue the process so that the area can have n values?

Comment: What do you mean by the area of a circle on a sphere not being unique?  If area is defined, it is unique. If it is not defined, there is nothing to discuss...

Comment: On a Riemannian surface, the area is determined by the (internal) metric.  If that metric is [flat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_manifold), then the surface can be "cut" and "unfolded", at least locally.  You may find interesting this [video](http://www.science4all.org/article/flat-torus/) about a flat torus embedded into a 3D Euclidian space.

Comment: @Alexey : Thank you for the fantastic video. Regarding the non uiquenes of cirlce on a sphere, start with circle being on equator of the circle and move it towards either of the poles, what would be definition of the area ?

Comment: You are talking about area, so you need to define it first, otherwise you have nothing to talk about.  If you want *me* to define area, i will use the standard definition of area by the [Riemannian volume form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_form#Riemannian_volume_form).

Comment: @Alexey : I am trying to say area can be non unique, not you have to define it. :)

Comment: "area can be non unique" makes no sens as stated. If it is defined, it is unique.  If you do not know how area is defined (and what it means in different contexts), i suggest that you post a separate question about it, but first check if such questions have already been asked here.

Comment: You may also be interested in [Gaussian curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_curvature).

Comment: On a sphere, a circle cuts the sphere into two pieces, each of which has an easily computed area. If you are doing differential geometry on an infinite cylinder embedded in $\mathbb R^3,$ the circles are not planar in $\mathbb R^3$. You can of course draw a curve on the cylinder that is circular in $\mathbb R^3,$ but in the geometry of the cylinder there is no point that all the points on that curve are equidistant from, so it isn't a circle on the cylinder. A helix in $\mathbb R^3,$ however, is a straight line in the geometry of the cylinder inscribed in the helix.

Comment: The answer seems to be that if the surface has zero Gaussian curvature (like a cylinder or cone) you can unroll it and preserve both lengths and areas perfectly. But if it has non-zero Gaussian curvature (like a sphere) you cannot flatten it in any way that preserves lengths and areas.

Comment: An obvious way to specify a circle on a manifold is to specify a point $C$ on the manifold (the center of the circle) and a radius $r$. The circle is the set of all points at a distance $r$ from $C.$ This set has zero area, but consider the _open disk_ of radius $r$ around $C$, which is the set of all points that are at a distance less than $r$ from $C.$ We measure the area of the set. You can obtain the same circle on a sphere in two ways, but when you specify it by a particular center $C$ and radius $r$, the area of the disk of radius $r$ around $C$ is uniquely defined.